# Regex find keywords in code

Tags: regex, perl, keyword

I'm attempting to find certain keywords inside a perl script. For some reason my Regex wont find keywords followed by a `;` and I believe `\n`

For example if I was searching for the word "print" the below code would find print if the string contained

> print ;

but wouldn't if it was

> print;

My current code:

```
$keyword = "print";
if($string =~/\b$keyword\b/g)
{
    print "found";
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea at all. May be [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/lib/PPI.pm) can be useful, never used though!

Answer (score 4):

use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) for parsing perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Find all the barewords within the doc
my $words = $doc->find( 'PPI::Token::Word' );
for (@$words) {
    print $_->content, "\n";
}

__DATA__
$keyword = "print";
if ($string =~/\b$keyword\b/g)
{
    print "found";
}
```

outputs:

```
if
print
```

Comment: Great solution! but is there no way of simply tailoring my Regex to find any kind of word even when they're next to `;`? To be honest I'm still surprised `\b` didn't work, or the below two answers.

Comment: It is not possible to help you anymore with your question as you have it written.  You do not include an actual working example of what is failing for you.  You say you have a string that contains the word print, but are not able to match it.  Then edit your post so that you actually define that string and attempt to match against it, then you will get better assistance:  [`How do I ask a good question?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($keyword =~ m/\bprint\b\s?;?/sim) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You may need to quote your variable. use \Q and \E in the regex. eg /\Q$var\E/g

UPDATE: this worked

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $keyword = "print";
my $string = 'print;';
if($string =~/\b$keyword\b/g)
{
    print "found";
}
```

Comment: see my update. can you tell us how your assigning the variables?